# cannot find symbol - method parameters

Tags: java, methods

Seems like a pointless post when you look at the title but i've been scouting SO for hours for a solution with no luck, maybe the screen is blinding me -_-

Anyway, the overloaded constructor of a particular class is throwing me a "cannot find symbol" compiler error and i've no idea why. The code causing my issue is this:-

```
public Student(String fname, String sname, int age, string ID, String avgGradeStr, String projectedGradeStr, String progTitle, int avgGradeInt, int projectedGradeInt, int progID, double attendance)
```

and the error originates at the `"int avgGradeInt"` argument.

Not to bombard you with code, the full class is as follows and if needed I can post the Person class also.

```
package DoC;
import java.util.*;

class Student extends Person
{

    protected String avgGradeStr, projectedGradeStr, progTitle;
    protected int avgGradeInt, projectedGradeInt, progID;
    protected double attendance;

    //CONSTRUCTOR
    public Student()
    {
        fname="Not";
        sname="Set";
        avgGradeStr="Not Set";
        ID="Not Set";
        projectedGradeStr="Not Set";
        progTitle="Not Set";

        avgGradeInt=0;
        projectedGradeInt=0;
        progID=0;
        attendance=0;
    }

    //CONSTRUCTOR (OVERLOADED)
    public Student(String fname, String sname, int age, string ID, String avgGradeStr, String projectedGradeStr, String progTitle, int avgGradeInt, int projectedGradeInt, int progID, double attendance)
    {
        fname=this.fname;
        sname=this.sname;
        age=this.age;
        ID=this.ID;
        avgGradeStr=this.avgGradeStr;
        projectedGradeStr=this.projectedGradeStr;
        progTitle=this.progTitle;

        avgGradeInt=this.avgGradeInt;
        projectedGradeInt=this.projectedGradeInt;
        progID=this.progID;
        attendance=this.attendance;
    }

    //GETTERS

    //get average grade string
    protected String getAvgGrade()
    {
        return avgGradeStr;
    }

    //get average grade integer
    protected int getAvgGradeInt()
    {
        return avgGradeInt;
    }

    //get projected grade string
    protected String getProjectedGrade()
    {
        return projectedGradeStr;
    }

    //get projected grade int
    protected int getProjectedGradeInt()
    {
        return projectedGradeInt;
    }

    //get attendance
    protected double getAttendance()
    {
        return attendance;
    }

    //get programme-of-study ID
    protected int getProgrammeID()
    {
        return progID;
    }

    //get programme-of-study title
    protected String getProgrammeTitle()
    {
        return progTitle;
    }
    //END GETTERS

    //START SETTERS

    //set programme id
    protected void setProgrammeID(int progID)
    {
        try{
            progID=this.progID;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("setProgrammeID() error: " + e);
        }
    }

    //set programme title
    protected void setProgrammeID(String progTitle)
    {
        try{
            progTitle=this.progTitle;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("setProgrammeTitle() error: " + e);
        }
    }

    //set average grade string
    protected void setAvgGrade(String avgGradeStr)
    {
        try{
            avgGradeStr=this.avgGradeStr;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("setAvgGrade() error: " +e);
        }
    }

    //set average grade int
    protected void setAvgGradeInt(int avgGradeInt)
    {
        try{
            avgGradeInt=this.avgGradeInt;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("setAvgGradeInt() error: " +e);
        }
    }

    //set projectede grade string
    protected void setProjectedGrade(String projectedGradeStr)
    {
        try{
            projectedGradeStr=this.projectedGradeStr;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("setProjectedGrade() error: " +e);
        }
    }

    //set projectede grade int
    protected void setProjectedGradeInt(int projectedGradeInt)
    {
        try{
            projectedGradeInt=this.projectedGradeInt;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("setProjectedGrade() error: " +e);
        }
    }
    //END SETTERS

} //END CLASS
```

As always, any help greatly appreciated guys!

Comment: Note that you assign the right side to the left side.

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`string ID` should be `String ID` (there's no `string` class in the Java API).

Also note that you should swap your assignments in your constructor.
Same for your setters.

I really recommend you to use an IDE (like Eclipse). You'll be able to correct these errors much more faster, than asking here =).

Comment: Thank you very much! Aye, I usually use eclipse for larger projects but this is a one day job and was meant to be reasonably simple lol. Seems I need a break, a fresh set of eyes is what I needed. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I see that you have `string ID` instead of `String ID`.  Sometimes mistakes like that cause the compiler to freak out and end up reporting the problem somewhere else.